# straight line form application for solving ship moving task

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

let us consider following problem

[image]

for  case  $a$ , i think answer will be

$y=30*t+6$

because  $30$ is slope and  $6$ is  $y$  intercept, what about  part $b$?does it represent  right triangle equation?

Comment: For a) you need $s(d)$, not $s(t)$. And no, $s(t)=30*t+6$ is wrong answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to draw a diagram for these types of problems.

[image: boat]

For part $(a)$, they want you to express the distance from the lighthouse to the boat as a function of $d$. As you mentioned, we have a right triangle setup. Find $s$ in terms of $d$ using the Pythagorean Theorem. This will give you $f(d)$.

For part $(b)$, they want $d$ as a function of time. After 1 hour, the boat travels 30km, after 2 hours, the boat travels 60km, after 3 hours the boat travels 90k, and so on. So... after $t$ hours, how far will the boat travel? This will give you $g(t)$.

Once you have both functions, you can find the composition $f(g(t))$ and interpret what that might mean by plugging in different values for $t$.

Comment: i see thanks in advance, for me  conditions of task was confusing now i got point

Comment: You are welcome @datodatuashvili . Glad to hear you got it!

Answer (score 0):

For (b): distance travelled in time $t$ when moving in a straight line with speed $30$ is $d(t) = 30*t$. It does not represent or use right triangle equation.

Comment: for part  $a$? why we need  $6$ ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Draw it on paper: the lighthouse, the position of ship at noon, present position of the ship. Express distance between lighthouse and present position $s$ in terms of distance between noon position and present position $d$, $s = s(d)$. Maybe 6 will be there somewhere.